# Navigation to child route gives me: "Error: Cannot match any routes" (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

The first example works (but it's bad writing).

```
const FooProcessingRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  redirectTo: '/foo-processing/list',
}, {
  path: 'list',
  component: FooListComponent,
}, {
  path: 'another-list',
  component: FooAnotherListComponent,
}, {
  path: 'another-list/:id/details',
  component: FooAnotherListComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: FooAnotherListDetailsComponent,
    outlet: 'details-view',
  }]
}];

export { FooProcessingRoutes };
```

The second example should work (in my opinion) and I want to have it that way:

```
const FooProcessingRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  redirectTo: '/foo-processing/list',
}, {
  path: 'list',
  component: FooListComponent,
}, {
  path: 'another-list',
  component: FooAnotherListComponent,
  children: [{
    path: ':id/details',
    outlet: 'details-view',
    component: FooAnotherListDetailsComponent,
  }],
}];

export { FooProcessingRoutes };
```

I need the `:id/details` to be a child of `another-list`. Both examples link to the same path in my browser (ie. http://localhost:4200/#/foo-processing/another-list/1/details).

However, the second example gives me `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'foo-processing/another-list/1/details'` in Chrome/Firefox.

Am I missing something there or is that a bug?

Comment: Maybe `/:id/details` ?

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
{
  path: 'another-list',
  component: FooAnotherListComponent,
  children: [{
    path: ':id/details',
    component: FooAnotherListDetailsComponent,
    outlet: 'details-view',
  }
```

Comment: you mean that component and outlet should switch places? is this the only change? because it still doesn't work after updating, sadly.

Comment: no, sorry i didn't read your second try, it should work now and remove ```outlet: 'details-view'```

Comment: I navigate to it by clicking a link on a column. It's not relevant here. Router outlet is necessary for embedding the view next to a table column. What matters is why the redundant-written example works and the second one doesn't.